# Elasticsearch - Aggregation on nested documents, using filter with has_child

Tags: elasticsearch

My index documents looks somewhat like this;

```
- a - Parent doc
 \- b - Nested doc (0 to many relation to a)
 \- c - Child doc (0 to many relation to a)
 \- d - Child doc (0 to many relation to a)
```

Info in a and b is "never" changed. Info in c and d is frequently changed and parent-child relation seems to be a perfect match.

Performing aggregation on b works just fine. Filter/query for a using c/d also works fine. When I try to combine "has_child" filter c/d and nested aggregation for b no aggregation is returned. Under _hits the correct number of parent a documents is returned (total).

Is there a way to perform this type of aggregation, or is this a limitation?

```
/someindex/a/_search
{
   "size": 0,
   "filter": {
     "has_child": {
       "type": "c",
       "filter": {
          "term": { "someFieldInC": 123}
         }
       }
     }
   }, 
  "aggregations" : {
     "details": {
        "nested": {
           "path": "b" 
         },
         "aggregations" : {
           "details-filter" : {
              "filter" : {
                 "query" : {
                    "term": {"b.someFieldInB": 123}
                 }
              },
              "aggregations" : {
                "some_count" : { 
                   "terms" : { 
                      "field" : "b.someCountFieldInB"
                   } 
                }
             }
           }
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Giving

```
{
  "took":22,
  "timed_out":false,
  "_shards": {
     "total":5,
     "successful":5,
     "failed":0
  },
  "hits":{
     "total":20134,
     "max_score":0.0,
     "hits":[]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I found the answere.

Simply moved the child filter into the aggregations at the top before my nested aggregation;

```
"aggregations" : {
   "childfilter" : { 
      "filter": {
         "has_child": {
            "type": "c",
            "query": {
               "match": {"someFieldInC": 123}
             }
         }
    },
    "aggregations" : {
       "details": {
          "nested": {
   . . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell your filter it is navigating a nested document as well.  Modify your request as follows:

```
  "aggregations" : {
     "details": {
        "nested": {
           "path": "b" 
         },
         "aggregations" : {
           "details-filter" : {
              "filter" : {
                 "nested": {
                    "path": "b",
                     "filter": {
                         "query" : {
                            "term": {"b.someFieldInB": 123}
                         }
                     }
                 }
              },
              "aggregations" : {
                "some_count" : { 
                   "terms" : { 
                      "field" : "b.someCountFieldInB"
                   } 
                }
             }
           }
        }
     }
```

Comment: Thanks Eric, I tried that but with no effect. I found a solution by simply moving my child filter to the top of the aggregation.